# Check the element length to flag status boolean

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, boolean

I am assigning as default `checked false` in this return Object, see the code

```
return Object.assign(file, {
    temp_id: _.uniqueId(),
    checked: false,
})
```

I have an exception, in case it is my first file dropped i want `checked: true`,

I know that my first file dropped is when

`const filePosition = files.length` returns `0`,

how can i apply this condition in my `checked`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to updated `checked` to `true` if `file.length === 0` and `false` and `file.length !== 0`

If that is correct, you can just do:

```
return Object.assign(file, {
    temp_id: _.uniqueId(),
    checked: files.length === 0,
})
```